# ORKTaskViewController - isNavigationBarHidden

Tags: swift, researchkit

Wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to hide the navigation controls only on a custom step inside a task, rather then on the entire taskviewcontroller via

```
tvc.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, the solution, if it's a custom ORKStep, is to set the visibility in the ORKStep that you've created.